# How to insert a value into the same index of array?

Tags: java, for-loop, hash

So I have an array that can store at least values. I let my user enter 3 times using for loop. The question is here is that, when the user enter the same key the value will overwrite. How to put the value into next index?

here is my entire code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class low{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int key = 0;
       // StringBuffer value = new StringBuffer();
       String value = "";
        ArrayList<String> hash = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] arr = new String[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            System.out.println("Key: ");
            key = Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());
            System.out.println("Value: ");
            value = sc.readLine();
            
            key++;
            arr[key] = value;
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
            
            System.out.println("Element at index " + x +  " : "+ arr[x]);  
           }
       
        
       
    }
}
```

Comment: just curious. is there particular reason to use `key++`?

Comment: Why not just count 0-3 instead of asking for the key?

Comment: by using a 2D array instead of an array

Comment: I need to find the next empty index because here is the situation. If the user enter the same key where should I put it? Of course in the next empty index and that is what I am trying to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a Map to store the values rather than array

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    int key = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
    if(key < 0 || key > 4) // it looks like you want the keys stay between [0,5)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid key");
    String value = in.nextLine();

    map.put(key,value);
}

for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.printf("Element at index %d : %s\n",entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: It's actually my assignment and we are only allowed to use an array

Comment: If the range of all `key`s is limited and continuous, you could use one array to store all the values and every index of that array is represent to a `key`. This is the same as your example code.

Comment: If the `key`s are random, the best way (when the only available data structure you could use is array) might be using two array to simulate `Map`. One for keys and one for values.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
key++;
arr[key] = value;
```

Do

```
if(arr[key] == null)
   arr[key + 1] = value;
else
    arr[key] = value;
```

But you’ll overwrite the information at index key + 1. You might want to rethink how you’re adding data.

Comment: this is not a solution. because, later on, he would have to be able to get all the data by obj = arr[1]; how would you distinguish how arr[2] was added?